# JQuery: выбрать все элементы от одного до другого

Tags: jquery, javascript, dom

Здравствуйте.

Есть таблица со строками, одни строки с классом L1, другие с классом L2.

Есть текущая строка с классом L1 и есть следующая строка с классом L1.

Между ними неизвестное количество строк с классом L2.

Подскажите как получить все строки класса с классом L2 между двумя строками с классом L1.

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[.nextUntil()](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) - там пара примеров, нужный вам код в одну строчку получается. Если вы не способны написать его, обратитесь к кому-нибудь, кто хоть чуть-чуть разбирается в JavaScript.

Comment: Спасибо. То что нужно.